# Weird Exception from SgmlReader

Tags: c#, xml, sgmlreader

I'm using SgmlReader to parse HTML files in C#. I'm using the sample code provided on their website:

```
using (reader = File.OpenText(fileName))
        {
            try
            {
                xmlDoc = fromHTML(reader);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return ReturnedCode.ErrorOpeningHTMLFile;
            }
        }
private XmlDocument fromHTML(TextReader reader)
    {
        Sgml.SgmlReader sgmlReader = new Sgml.SgmlReader();
        sgmlReader.DocType = "HTML";
        sgmlReader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.All;
        sgmlReader.CaseFolding = Sgml.CaseFolding.ToLower;
        sgmlReader.InputStream = reader;
        //  create document
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
        doc.Load(sgmlReader);
        return doc;
    }
```

The code has been running for a long time without any issue. However, recently it started throwing the following exception at `doc.Load(sgmlReader)` line:

> A valid UTF32 value is between 0x000000 and 0x10ffff, inclusive, and should not include surrogate codepoint values (0x00d800 ~ 0x00dfff).\r\nParameter name: utf32

I was able to narrow down the problem to the below content of the HTML file. If I try to parse a file containing the below code, the exception will be thrown.

```
<html>
<br>&#121669935008
</html>
```

If I remove the ampersand in the second line, the code will work normally.

Any idea what's happening here and how can I fix it? I cannot simply remove all the ampersands in the files.

Comment: Can you please [edit] to clarify what part of the error message needs to be explained? Clearly `1C5417DFA0` is *not* "between 0x000000 and 0x10ffff"...

Comment: What is that HTML *intended* to represent? Is the ampersand *intended* to be part of escaping something (in which case, what is the expected resulting character?) or is it intended to be "just an ampersand" in which case it should be encoded as `&amp;`?

Comment: (And where did the broken files come from? It's generally better to try to fix the production of them than trying to patch already-broken data.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `&` character is an escape character in XML, so you need to tack on it's unicode value at the end, every time `&` appears in your data, thus ensuring that there are no XML parsing errors. How you can do this is replace all `&` with `&#038;`.

Comment: Thank you. This is actually the correct answer. The exception is thrown because C# treats &#12.. as the ascii code of some character.